# How to allow duplicates on many to many relationship

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I would like to allow my users to borrow books. Whenever a user borrows a book

```js
   const userBook = await UserBook.create({
        UserId,
        BookId,
        status: 0,
      });
```

And when some user returns

```js
      await userBook.update({ status: 1 });
      userBook.save();
```

Everything works as expected. But whenever the same user tries to borrow and old book I got a duplication error.

```js
{
    code: 'ER_DUP_ENTRY',
    errno: 1062,
    sqlState: '23000',
    sqlMessage: "Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'UserBooks.PRIMARY'",
    sql: 'INSERT INTO `UserBooks` (`status`,`UserId`,`BookId`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);',
    parameters: [ 0, '1', '1', '2023-08-26 12:55:03', '2023-08-26 12:55:03' ]
  },
  fields: { PRIMARY: '1-1' },
  sql: 'INSERT INTO `UserBooks` (`status`,`UserId`,`BookId`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);'
}
```

This is my **User** model

```js
module.exports = (sequelize) => {
  const { DataTypes, Model } = require('sequelize');
  class User extends Model {}

  User.init(
    {
      name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      timestamps: true,
      deletedAt: true,
      modelName: 'User',
    }
  );
  User.associations = () => {
    User.belongsToMany(sequelize.models.Book, {
      through: { model: sequelize.models.UserBook, unique: false },
      constraints: false,
    });
  };
  return User;
};
```

This is my **Book** model

```js
module.exports = (sequelize) => {
  const { DataTypes, Model } = require('sequelize');
  class Book extends Model {}

  Book.init(
    {
      name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      timestamps: true,
      deletedAt: true,
      modelName: 'Book',
    }
  );
  Book.associations = () => {
    Book.belongsToMany(sequelize.models.User, {
      through: { model: sequelize.models.UserBook, unique: false },
      constraints: false,
    });
  };
  return Book;
};
```

And this is my **UserBook** model

```js
module.exports = (sequelize) => {
  const { DataTypes, Model } = require('sequelize');
  class UserBook extends Model {}

  UserBook.init(
    {
      status: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false },
      UserId: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false },
      BookId: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false },
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      timestamps: true,
      deletedAt: true,
      modelName: 'UserBook',
    }
  );

  UserBook.associations = () => {
    UserBook.hasOne(sequelize.models.Book, {
      constraints: false,
    });
    UserBook.hasOne(sequelize.models.User, {
      constraints: false,
    });
  };
  return UserBook;
};
```

This is the sequelize that i initialize

```js
  const sequelize = new Sequelize({
    username: '*****',
    password: '*****',
    database: '*****',
    host: '*****',
    dialect: 'mysql',
  });
```

```
Example Scenerio I want:  |  UserBook Table
userId 1 borrows bookId 1 -> id:1 status:0, userId:1, bookId:1
userId 1 returns bookId 1 -> id:1 status:1, userId:1, bookId:1
userId 1 borrows bookId 1 -> id:2 status:0, userId:1, bookId:1
userId 1 returns bookId 1 -> id:2 status:1, userId:1, bookId:1
```

Also i tried to add `primaryKey:true` to userBook fields

```js
...
...
 UserBook.init(
    {
      status: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey:true, allowNull: false },
      UserId: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey:true, allowNull: false },
      BookId: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey:true, allowNull: false },
    },
...
...
```

And this is the `package.json` file

```js
"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mysql2": "^3.6.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.32.1",
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.6.1"
  }
```